# Show errors during decoding QRcode. Using ZXing Java library

Tags: qr-code, zxing, decoding

I am trying to decode QR code with errors in Java with ZXing library. And I want to get all position of errors in binary string (consist from data and RS error correction codewords), which have decoded into QR code. How I can use ZXing library (or modify it) and solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to try reading the source first. In `com.google.zxing.common.reedsolomon.ReedSolomonDecoder`, there is a method `findErrorLocations()` which pretty clear does exactly this.

Comment: Please, can you help me with realization this task? In first, there is image (bitmap), which has decoded by algorithm (ZXing for android source). I don't know, how use this method for scanned image.